# Spring JAX-RS: End point not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I followed the same steps defined in this post: https://java2blog.com/restful-web-services-jaxrs-crud-example/#comment-11493 . I did not change any file in my local yet. But finally, http://localhost:8080/JAXRSJsonCRUDExample/rest/countries saying 404 issue. http://localhost:8080/JAXRSJsonCRUDExample/ is showing “Hello World” in the browser.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide a [mcve] so that other people can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the below is working, then configurations are correct

```
http://localhost:8080/JAXRSJsonCRUDExample/
```

and then the below url giving 404 issue(file/resource not found)

```
http://localhost:8080/JAXRSJsonCRUDExample/rest/countries
```

this means no service is matching with the above url.

please check the path properly (add `@Path("")` in respective method if needed)